# Is there any oracle solution available for substrate based solo chain?

Tags: offchain-worker, solo-chain

We have a Substrate based solo chain where we need to fetch external data like ETH/USD price using off-chain workers right now. But these OCW doesn't work for reaching consensus on data being fetched and put on chain. is there any substrate based oracle available for solo-chain and not parachain?

Comment: There is an example here: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/tree/master/frame/examples/offchain-worker
- this is just an example, not for production.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Acurast data providers](http://docs.acurast.com/developers/introduction#complete-example), which allow you to delegate the execution of arbitrary javascript code inside a [TEE](https://source.android.com/docs/security/features/trusty)(Trusted Execution Environment)

Our solution is currently at phase 0, where you can schedule jobs in a smart-contract. There, you provide the IPFS hash of the javascript code you want to execute and the period of execution for the job.

In phase 0, jobs can only be registered on request. Let me know if you are interested.

The upcoming Acurast version will have its own parachain with a marketplace and a reputation system, where anyone can become a data consumer and a processor.

You can also join our channels for more information about the project:

- https://twitter.com/Acurast
- https://t.me/acurastnetwork
- https://acurast.medium.com

Answer (score 1):

You can create a Phat Contract that pulls data from whatever HTTPS endpoint to gather price feed data. We have a workshop here to show the capabilities as Phala’s Phat Contracts run in our Secure Enclave offchain workers and can create ACID txs with the offchain rollup pallet which you can integrate into your runtime for your substrate solo chain.

Check the details here: https://github.com/Phala-Network/phat-offchain-rollup/blob/main/phat/Sub0-Workshop.md

Let me know if you have any questions.